# Different Web browsing on each squid port

Tags: squid, fedora

I have a server with two network adapters, one connected to an isolated network and the other one to internet. Right now i'm sharing internet throught squid (not transparent proxy) with a few machines inside the isolated network. This machines has no browsing restriction, but **i want to give access just to google maps for some more PC's. Is this possible with squid**?

I have readen about using more than one port, and i imagined to configure full service in one port and just google maps service in another port (on same server ip), but i can't find any example about this or any way to do it. Another possibility would be running multiple instances of squid, but i prefer leave this as last choice.

Note: as @mattdm said, this could be done easly with ACL, but i think that he means by IP. Sorry, what i didn't explain is that i don't want make changes to squid configuration any time that a PC needs different browsing access. But for security reasons i think it wold be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is very easily done with Squid ACLs — access control lists. Documentation for this is here: https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

(You don't even need to use different ports for this.)

Comment: Sorry, my fault. What i didn't explain is that i was thinking to use different port because i don't want to configure it by IP, because any new PC or any change in configuration means a Squid service restart. But i think this wold be the best approach. I think is the correct answer, just let me see if any one have a look a like idea.

Comment: @FoxEdu Note that you can also require a login and give different access to different logins... https://wiki.squid-cache.org/action/show/Features/Authentication